# Why is pip install libvirt-python failing and saying I need libvirt installed, even though libvirt is installed?

Tags: python, rhel, kvm, libvirt, rhel9

I am running RHEL 9.2 with Python v3.9.16, and I am trying to install the [libvirt-python](https://pypi.org/project/libvirt-python/) Python package. I have tried installing using pip and pipenv, and I get the same error every time.

I have the libvirt and KVM packages installed (via dnf) and working. I am able to interact with VMs with virsh through the cli.

I have read the other similar posts on stack, and those solutions didn't work for me. Any suggestions on what might be the issue?

```
$ pip install libvirt-python

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting libvirt-python
  Downloading libvirt-python-9.7.0.tar.gz (132 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 132.1/132.1 kB 6.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: libvirt-python
  Building wheel for libvirt-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for libvirt-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [51 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Package 'libvirt' was not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/bill/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/bill/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/bill/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 284, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/normal/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-cx5clem5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 166, in run
        File "<string>", line 35, in check_minimum_libvirt_version
        File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--atleast-version=0.9.11', 'libvirt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for libvirt-python
Failed to build libvirt-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for libvirt-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Here are the libvirt related packages I have installed:

```
$ sudo dnf list | grep libvirt

libvirt.x86_64                                       9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-client.x86_64                                9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon.x86_64                                9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-config-network.x86_64                 9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-config-nwfilter.x86_64                9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-interface.x86_64               9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-network.x86_64                 9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-nodedev.x86_64                 9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-nwfilter.x86_64                9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu.x86_64                    9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-secret.x86_64                  9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage.x86_64                 9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-core.x86_64            9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-disk.x86_64            9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-iscsi.x86_64           9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-logical.x86_64         9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-mpath.x86_64           9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd.x86_64             9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-scsi.x86_64            9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-daemon-kvm.x86_64                            9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-dbus.x86_64                                  1.4.1-5.el9                         @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-glib.x86_64                                  4.0.0-3.el9                         @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-libs.x86_64                                  9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
pcp-pmda-libvirt.x86_64                              6.0.1-5.el9_2                       @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
python3-libvirt.x86_64                               9.0.0-1.el9                         @rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
fence-virtd-libvirt.x86_64                           4.10.0-43.el9                       rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
fence-virtd-libvirt.x86_64                           4.10.0-43.el9                       rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
libvirt-nss.x86_64                                   9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms
libvirt-nss.x86_64                                   9.0.0-10.3.el9_2                    rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
```

Comment: That output is a bit confusing.  Why does it start with `$ pip install libvirt-python`, and then the next line is `libvirt-experiment]$ pip install libvirt-python` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy/paste error. I updated the post.

Comment: You probably need the libvirt development libraries (`libvirt-devel`), but why are you running `pip install libvirt-python` instead of just `dnf install python3-libvirt`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to install libvirt-devel via yum and dnf and got a packaged not found error.

I am writing a python script that interacts with libvirt, so I need to import the libvirt-python package inside of the python script.

I already have python3-libvirt installed.